# A difficult problem about the "FindRoot"

Tags: numerical-integration

[image][image][image][image][image][image: i can't calculate the Pi in the final, and i can't understand the caution]

I use the parameters to calculate the Φ in the final, but I don't know what happen, it shows a lot of information, but I can't understand. I am using this code to solve the problem. This code is borrowed by me. With the consent of others, then I have not changed anything, but I can't display the final result. The main problem is in the last calculation 'FindRoot'. Follow is my code.

Hope somebody can help me, thank you very much! Cause this problem is very important to me!

```
(* Physical Constants *)
k = 1.38 * 10^-23;
\[Epsilon] = 8.85 * 10^-12;
e = 1.6 *10^-19;
m0 = 9.11 * 10^-31;
h = 6.63 * 10^-34;

(* Basic information of Black Phosphorus *)
\[Kappa] = 6.1;
me = 0.13 * m0;
mp = 0.28 * m0;
Eg = 0.33;
\[CapitalDelta]\[Phi] = -0.1;
(* \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi] = \[Phi]Tip - \[Chi] *)
\[CapitalDelta]V = 0.04;
(* \[CapitalDelta]V = EA - EV *)

(* Experimental conditions *)
T = 4.3;
\[CapitalDelta]S = 0.4*10^-9;
(* Distance between tip and sample *)
ni = 2/h^3*(2*\[Pi]*k*T)^(3/2)*(me*mp)^(3/4)*E^(-((Eg*e)/(2*k*T)));
uB = (e*\[Phi]B)/(k*T);
NA = 10^22;
ND = 0;
X = FindRoot[-(NA/(
    1 + 4*E^(((\[CapitalDelta]V - 1/2 Eg - \[Phi]B)*e)/(k*T)))) == 
   2*ni*Sinh[uB], {\[Phi]B, 1/2 Eg}]
\[Phi]B = \[Phi]B /. X;
uB = (e*\[Phi]B)/(k*T);
LD = ((\[Kappa]*\[Epsilon]*k*T)/(2*e^2*ni))^(1/2);
Result = FindRoot[(k*T)/e*1/
    LD*(NA/ni*
       Log[(1 + 
         1/2*E^((e*\[Phi]S)/(k*T) - ((\[CapitalDelta]V - 1/2*Eg)*e)/(
           k*T)))/(
        1 + 1/2*E^((e*\[Phi]B)/(
           k*T) - ((\[CapitalDelta]V - 1/2*Eg)*e)/(k*T)))] - 1/\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(
\*FractionBox[
SuperscriptBox[\(x\), 
FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)]], \(1 + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(x - 
\*FractionBox[\(\(-Eg\)*e\), \(2*k*
               T\)]\)]\)] \[DifferentialD]x\)\)*(2/3*\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(
\*FractionBox[
SuperscriptBox[\(x\), 
FractionBox[\(3\), \(2\)]], \(1 + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(x - 
\*FractionBox[\(\(-Eg\)*e\), \(2*k*T\)] + 
\*FractionBox[\(e*\[Phi]B\), \(k*T\)]\)]\)] \[DifferentialD]x\)\) - 
         2/3*\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(
\*FractionBox[
SuperscriptBox[\(x\), 
FractionBox[\(3\), \(2\)]], \(1 + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(x - 
\*FractionBox[\(\(-Eg\)*e\), \(2*k*T\)] + 
\*FractionBox[\(e*\[Phi]S\), \(k*T\)]\)]\)] \[DifferentialD]x\)\)) + 
      1/\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(
\*FractionBox[
SuperscriptBox[\(x\), 
FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)]], \(1 + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(x - 
\*FractionBox[\(\(-Eg\)*e\), \(2*k*
               T\)]\)]\)] \[DifferentialD]x\)\)*(2/3*\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(
\*FractionBox[
SuperscriptBox[\(x\), 
FractionBox[\(3\), \(2\)]], \(1 + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(x + 
\*FractionBox[\(Eg*e\), \(2*k*T\)] - 
\*FractionBox[\(e*\[Phi]S\), \(k*T\)]\)]\)] \[DifferentialD]x\)\) - 
         2/3*\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(
\*FractionBox[
SuperscriptBox[\(x\), 
FractionBox[\(3\), \(2\)]], \(1 + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(x + 
\*FractionBox[\(Eg*e\), \(2*k*T\)] - 
\*FractionBox[\(e*\[Phi]B\), \(k*T\)]\)]\)] \[DifferentialD]x\)\)))^(
    1/2)*(-\[CapitalDelta]S) == \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi] - 
    1/2*Eg + \[Phi]B - (\[Phi]S - \[Phi]B), {\[Phi]S, -(1/2) Eg}]
\[Phi] = (\[Phi]S /. Result[[1]]) - \[Phi]B
```

enter image description here

Comment: Please provide Mathematica code to ease answering .  As far as I can identify your screenshot there are some parameters which aren't defined!!! FindRoot is a numerical solver and needs numerical input!

Comment: (* Physical Constants *)
k = 1.38 * 10^-23;
\[Epsilon] = 8.85 * 10^-12;
e = 1.6 *10^-19;
m0 = 9.11 * 10^-31;
h = 6.63 * 10^-34;

(* Basic information of Black Phosphorus *)
\[Kappa] = 6.1;
me = 0.13 * m0;
mp = 0.28 * m0;
Eg = 0.33;
\[CapitalDelta]\[Phi] = -0.1;
(* \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi] = \[Phi]Tip - \[Chi] *)
\[CapitalDelta]V = 0.04;
(* \[CapitalDelta]V = EA - EV *)

(* Experimental conditions *)
T = 4.3;
\[CapitalDelta]S = 0.4*10^-9;
(* Distance between tip and sample *)

Comment: I am a freshman of this Web, and i don't know how to post the code,i just copy this, thank you very much if someone teach me how to do it. Thank you very much

Comment: Your equation (inside FindRoot) is very hard to understand and does not evaluate numerical. For example  I tried to solve one integral  `\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(
\*FractionBox[
SuperscriptBox[\(x\), 
FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)]], \(1 + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(x - 
\*FractionBox[\(\(-Eg\)*e\), \(2*k*T\)]\)]\)] \[DifferentialD]x\)\) ` which evalutes to `5.40267*10^-194` . Probably the problem is poorly scaled.

Comment: Can i know your version of your MMA? In my view, maybe is the problem of the version

Comment: Your answer is right. But in my MMA, i can't get this value. you can see from the first picture.

Comment: My version is 11.0.1 (Windows)!

Comment: In your opinion, does the difference of the version can cause this problem?

Comment: The code did not cut-paste into something I could run. I recommend you first convert it to Mathematica `InputForm`. This can be done by selecting the cell with cursor, then going to menu `Cell > ConvertTo > InputForm`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to read your code...

With two corrections   I found a solution:

First, inside the parameter definition you should include `Clear[\[Phi]B ]` before the line `X=FindRoot...`

```
Clear[\[Phi]B ]
X = FindRoot[-(NA/(1 + 4*E^(((\[CapitalDelta]V - 1/2 Eg - \[Phi]B)*e)/(k*T)))) ==2*ni*Sinh[uB], {\[Phi]B, 1/2 Eg}]
\[Phi]B = \[Phi]B /. X;
uB = (e*\[Phi]B)/(k*T);
LD = ((\[Kappa]*\[Epsilon]*k*T)/(2*e^2*ni))^(1/2);
```

Secondly, you need additional brackets inside your equation. Mathematica cannot handle expressions like this

[image]

without parenthesis!!!

```
eq = Simplify[(k*T)/e*1/LD*(NA/ni*Log[(1 + 1/2*E^((e*\[Phi]S)/(k*T) - ((\[CapitalDelta]V -1/2*Eg)*e)/(k*T)))/(1 + 1/2*E^((e*\[Phi]B)/(k*T) - ((\[CapitalDelta]V - 1/2*Eg)*e)/(k*T)))] - 1/(\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(\*FractionBox[SuperscriptBox[\(x\), FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)]], \(1 +\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(x - \*FractionBox[\(\(-Eg\)*e\), \(2*k*T\)]\)]\)] \[DifferentialD]x\)\))*(2/3*\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(\*FractionBox[SuperscriptBox[\(x\), FractionBox[\(3\), \(2\)]], \(1 + \*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(x - \*FractionBox[\(\(-Eg\)*e\), \(2*k*T\)]+\*FractionBox[\(e*\[Phi]B\), \(k*T\)]\)]\)] \[DifferentialD]x\)\) - 2/3*\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(\*FractionBox[SuperscriptBox[\(x\), FractionBox[\(3\), \(2\)]], \(1+\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(x - \*FractionBox[\(\(-Eg\)*e\), \(2*k*T\)]+\*FractionBox[\(e*\[Phi]S\), \(k*T\)]\)]\)] \[DifferentialD]x\)\)) +1/(\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(\*FractionBox[SuperscriptBox[\(x\), FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)]], \(1+\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(x - \*FractionBox[\(\(-Eg\)*e\), \(2*k*T\)]\)]\)] \[DifferentialD]x\)\))*(2/3*\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(\*FractionBox[SuperscriptBox[\(x\), FractionBox[\(3\), \(2\)]], \(1 + \*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(x + \*FractionBox[\(Eg*e\), \(2*k*T\)] - \*FractionBox[\(e*\[Phi]S\), \(k*T\)]\)]\)] \[DifferentialD]x\)\) - 2/3*\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(\*FractionBox[SuperscriptBox[\(x\),FractionBox[\(3\), \(2\)]], \(1 +\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(x +\*FractionBox[\(Eg*e\), \(2*k*T\)] -\*FractionBox[\(e*\[Phi]B\), \(k*T\)]\)]\)] \[DifferentialD]x\)\)))^(1/2)*(-\[CapitalDelta]S) == \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi] -1/2*Eg + \[Phi]B - (\[Phi]S - \[Phi]B)]
```

Now the equation can be solved:

```
FindRoot[eq, {\[Phi]S, -(1/2) Eg}]
(*{\[Phi]S -> 0.0650047 - 0.000974413 I}*)
```

Comment: The first thing that you wrote is doesn't matter, cause i can run this part of code, just the second part to solve the [Phi]S , i can not get the value. The value that the writer who wrote the code give is [Phi]S= -0.324431

Comment: The first thing matters only if you want to run your code twice! Can you reproduce the result I posted?